# How to port __declspec(noalias) on GCC

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc, alias, restrict-qualifier

If I get it correctly, `__declspec(noalias)` tells the compiler that none of the pointers passed as parameters is aliased.

```
__declspec(noalias) void multiply(float * a, float * b, float * c)
{
    ...
}
```

Said differently, if I’m not mistaken , it’s exactly equivalent to calling `__restrict` on every parameter of pointer type. But is there a way to do it without changing all the function calls? Ideally, I would replace that `__declspec(noalias)` with a preprocessor definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're interpreting `noalias` incorrectly; it is not the same as specifying `__restrict` on each parameter. In the [example you reference from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k649tyc7.aspx), it means that `a`, `b`, and `c` don't modify or reference any global state (of the current compilation unit), but they are free to alias one another. You could *also* specify `__restrict` on each one to indicate that they do not alias each other. I'm not sure why you mention changing all the function calls in this scenario; as long as no caller aliases the arguments, nothing changes at the call site. You should *review* all the calls, but they needn't change unless you need to remove aliasing. Specifically, `__restrict` is *not* needed at the call site.

The only analogue in GCC would be to specify `__restrict` (or [more commonly for GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html), `__restrict__`) on any global pointer variable declarations in the same source file (which are of compatible types). See [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris10/cc-restrict-139391.html) about file-scope `restrict`-qualified pointers. Of course, there's no guarantee that GCC will behave any differently, since `restrict` is often considered only at function scope. Microsoft clearly introduced `noalias` to enable a specific optimization they introduced.

Long story short, there's no macro trick here (aside from the one mentioned by R to ignore `__declspec()` entirely on GCC). The best you can do is add `__restrict` to any non-aliased pointer parameter and global variable declarations.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! The difference is now clearer

Answer (score 2):

<s>The correct</s> The closest gcc/clang analogue for `__declspec(noalias)` is `__attribute__((const))` - *not* restrict:  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-const-function-attribute

`noalias` says more than "the arguments do not reference globals": it says the function does not access or modify global state, through the arguments or not. `noalias` is a rather unfortunate choice of terminology.

Note @NateEldredge's comment for an important difference between the two.

Comment: Still, "Note that a function that has pointer arguments and examines the data pointed to must not be declared const if the pointed-to data might change between successive invocations of the function".  Is that true of `noalias` too?

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you! You're right, I wasn't aware of this attribute-const restriction. Just tested it, and indeed gcc reduces multiple calls to a single one: https://godbolt.org/z/j61318Ynj , and msvc doesn't: https://godbolt.org/z/f7Ysdzbq8.

Comment: @NateEldredge [`__attribute__((pure))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-pure-function-attribute) might work:  "The `pure` attribute imposes similar but looser restrictions on a function’s definition than the `const` attribute: ..."

Comment: @AndrewHenle MS docs say "noalias means that a function call doesn't modify *or reference* visible global state". This is much closer to `const` than `pure`.

Comment: @OfekShilon But if `const` is too restrictive from a caller perspective, `pure`'s "does not affect their return value or the observable state of the program" *might* suffice from the caller's viewpoint, even if it is a looser restriction on what the actual function *could* do.

Answer (score -1):

Just `#define __declspec(x)` (to a blank definition). Omitting noalias/restrict will not make any change to the *behavior* of a correct program. All it does is create additional (usually very minor, with current compiler technology) opportunities for the compiler to optimize.

Comment: +1 for the idea, but I can’t accept this as a solution. The context is video gaming, `__restrict` is not an option :)

Comment: Have you measured the difference in performance with/without "noalias" on Windows? Premature optimization is the root of all evil. The time you're wasting trying to find a solution to this problem could probably be better spent just optimizing higher-level inefficiencies in the code...

Comment: I couldn’t agree more with you on that point. But even if the optimization was pointless in my case, I could imagine that a future reader would really need a solution for that.